# set cookie on the chrome extensions (chrome://extensions) for google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm new to chrome extension development. we've needed to trace our customers for out service growth. **so we've been wanting to get the metric for retention of our users.** but there were some wired thing that same number of users each user type was traced. I attached it below. this is **Google Analytics Cohort Analysis** of our service.

[a screenshot on the google analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m12Pj.png)

**but I think Event metrics(Behavior > Events) are being collected correctly.** screenshot is here.
[Google Analytics > Behavior > Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ess9q.png)

so I looked for Google Analytics users. and I've figured out that **Google’s tracking snippet looks for a tracking cookie on user's device.** site address is here. https://www.hotjar.com/google-analytics/glossary/users/

according to these documents, **Google uses cookie to distinguish user type between new users and returning user.** so I've set the **checkProtocolTask** option to **false** into GTM console like this. cuz chrome extension doesn't have http or https protocols.
[Google Tag Manager Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRReS.png)

but user cohort is still weird. I really wanna get correct result of new users cohort analysis.

**question**

- why google analytics shows us weird cohort result?
- what can I do for this more?

my english ability is not good and I don't know Google Analytics well so my questions are kind of a mess. please understand me

thanks for reading this question!

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you're trying to use GA for extension tracking? Like you have a Chrome extension and you want to get some data on its usage? And more than that, you have GTM in an extension?

Comment: @Cthulchu yes! I've already added GTM in our service. but Cohort Analysis data is incorrect I think  (first screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for Extension tracking, I have never heard of people using GTM for extension tracking. That doesn't sound correct to me. Just because of how GTM deploys analytics, expecting there to be a standard window scope, relying on all the standard window.location values and many other properties and like the resolution, viewport, "this" and such.

Moreover, since you're a JS developer and you're not going to delegate tracking to non-JS devs, you probably want to use GA's measurement protocol directly rather than completely relying on the default library through GTM.

With the measurement protocol, you will be able to explicitly set all the fields you're interested in, including client IDs. You will have to manage user cookies on your side, but it's easier than trying to force web tracking logic to work for extensions.

Here is the parameter reference. It may be very useful to you: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters

And here is an npm lib that implements measurement protocol. I use it with Node, but it can definitely be used on the front-end too: https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-analytics

I actually tried quite a bit of npm packages for measurement protocol usage and I found this one the most comfortable for me. There's a lot of them. Feel free to browse.